Dual-independent turbo engine possibilities
My coach wants to mod his engine, so I was throwing around the idea of possible turbo setups. One that I started to like the idea of was the idea of two turbos, working independently. Is it possible to have a smaller turbo spooling for low rpm boost, and then a separate larger turbo work for higher rpm boost; as a way to compensate for turbo lag? My coach is skeptical of something like this being possible. but after thinking it through (as a math person, not an engineering person) I don't see why it wouldn't be viable.

Yes, jag does it on my xf 3 litre diesel.
First turbo only up to about 2500 rpm then the second comes in so they are sequential.
Also, some engine manufacturers use two smaller turbos so they spin up quicker at low rpm to avoid the turbo lag, dumping excess boost at lower rpm until needed, so they look at engine load parameters as well.

another way to eliminate turbo lag is to run the boost pump off electricity instead of exhaust gas. there are race cars that do this.

@nielsnielsen or a supercharger driven from the crankshaft... But turbos use the energy in the exhaust gas while your solution uses power from the alternator or battery & the supercharger uses power directly from the crank.

Certainly have been diesel engines that used both supercharger and turbo charger for better power and response. Volvo S90, Volkswagen, Skoda, Audi.

Can you do it? Yes.  Is it much much harder?  Also yes.  Most engines have a community which has settled on the best turbo to use for upgrading the engine.  Just get to the right online forum and use what they have already figured out.
